# How to lazy load Angular module without CLI?

Tags: angular, webpack, module, lazy-loading

I have yet to find this specific use case described any where. If it exists, please refer me to it.

I would like to achieve lazy loading of Angular modules (using Angular version 7), because we use many large 3rd party libraries for specific parts of our app that are rarely used. However, we do not use the Angular CLI (ng command). All examples I have seen use Angular CLI to build the module chunk, and load via a path string, either in `loadChildren` or some other way.

Our build is managed with Webpack (webpack.config.js file). My understanding is that Angular CLI is a build tool, and use of Angular does not require it. Since we know this functionality exists in Angular, there must be a way to leverage it without the CLI. I don't mind hacky solutions to this, as it is my hope that this feature may be more robustly introduced in the future to the Angular framework.

Any crumb of information will be appreciated.

Comment: The Angular CLI is open source. Go see how they do it.

Comment: As you rightly said, CLI is an abstraction wrapper over Webpack. So one way to understand how cli does it is by creating a sample app with lazy loaded modules. Then use `ng eject` to eject the underlying Webpack config. It should contain the correct loaders and script to generate and load the chunks.

Comment: That would be an interesting idea. I had tried that once, but `ng eject` is no longer available in Angular 7. I will need to figure out if there is an older version of Angular with `ng eject` and lazy modules.

Answer (score 0):

> All examples I have seen use Angular CLI to build the module chunk, and load via a path string, either in loadChildren or some other way.

That's right, but if you don't use Angular CLI, the next thing you have to do is to install `angular-router-loader` package and afterwards in your `webpack.config.js file` you add it to to your typescript loaders:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      'awesome-typescript-loader'
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
    loaders: [
      'angular-router-loader'
    ]
  }  
]
```